# Is it possible to use a SFC Vue component as a mixin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-sfc

For example, I have a component written in SFC format:

```js
// Parent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    {{ txt }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      txt: 'Hello, world! I\'m Parent'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sayHello() {
      console.log(this.txt);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And I would like to reuse the component above from which I can extend:

```js
// Child.vue
<template>
  <div>
    {{ txt }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from './Parent';

export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  mixins: [ParentComponent],
  created() {
    this.sayHello(); // 'Hello, world! I'm Parent'
  }
}
</script>
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to use like this fashion?
2. If possible, then I can understand that the vue component properties like `data`, `methods`, ... will be integrated in `ChildComponent` as that is a basic behavior of Vue mixin. But what about `<template>` part? How the markup parts are integrated together? Or is it ignored so that the only `<script>` part is merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Yes it's possible but using `extends` option instead of `mixins` :

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ txt }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from './Parent';

export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  extends: ParentComponent,
  created() {
    this.sayHello(); 
  }
}
</script>
```

2 - This inherits only the extended component options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the both (using `extends` and `mixins`), and they all work, then what is different with each other?

Comment: Self-reply: Maybe [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-composing-components) can be helpful